# Regex help to add rel="nofollow" to links matching a predefined URL pattern

Tags: php, regex

The function below parses through the content passed from the filter and adds ***rel="nofollow"*** to all external links it finds and currently skips over all internal links.

Assuming that I have a folder path defined in a variable, say...

```
$my_folder = "http://mysite.com/recommends/";
```

How would I augment the function so that it also ads the nofollow to links that match this pattern as well? These will likely be internal links, and these would be the only internal links I would want to nofollow in this example, so they need to be exceptioned from the internal link regex bits somehow.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'new_content' );
function new_content($content) {
preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);
for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){
    if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i])
        && !preg_match( '~'.get_bloginfo('url').'~',$matches[0][$i])  ){
        $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
        $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
        $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
    }
}
return $content;
```

}

PS: Thanks to Backie from WSX for the current function code...

Comment: From my experience such tasks are much easier to manage with a dom parser or with xpath.

Answer (score 1):

I have no way to try this out since I'm not a WP user, but assuming your inner loop defines `$matches[0][$i]` as the current url to compare:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'new_content' );
    function new_content($content) {
    $my_folder =  "http://mysite.com/recommends/";
    preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){
        if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i])
            && (preg_match('~' . $my_folder . '~', $matches[0][$i]) 
               || !preg_match( '~'.get_bloginfo('url').'~',$matches[0][$i]))){
            $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
            $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
            $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Edit: Might have to add a preg_quote around $my_folder, I'm just a bit confused since it's not done for get_bloginfo('url')

Comment: Seems to work fine in my initial testing. About preg_quote? Are you thinking it should be like this > && (preg_match('~' . preg_quote($my_folder) . '~', $matches[0][$i])

Comment: Yes. Can't hurt, just to be safe.

Comment: Ok I guess this was the last time I actually wrote somebody's code, since you didn't even vote/accept it seems like it wasn't helpful...

Comment: crashd0wn,
correct this: for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){ with for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){